# How to make 2-way/2-d radio-button mutex (exclusivity)

Tags: jquery, radio-button, 2d, mutex

I was looking for a way to make a grid of radio buttons where the "Mutually exclusive" feature of them works in two directions. The idea is to only allow one selection of all the buttons in a particular row - but also only one of all the buttons in a particular column.

I've actually answered my own question, but I thought I'd post it here since I didn't find the question itself, and it seems like it could be generally useful.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xdL8jyvL/) demonstrating my solution.

The basic gist of it is to use normal radio button technique in one direction, e.g. horizontally, and to use arrange for a selector to match the whole column in the other direction - I've used a css class.

Then, on click, uncheck the whole column, before checking `this`.

html:

```
<input class=one type=radio name=foo value=1/>
<input class=two type=radio name=foo value=2/>
<input class=three type=radio name=foo value=3/>
<br/>
<input class=one type=radio name=bar value=1/>
<input class=two type=radio name=bar value=2/>
<input class=three type=radio name=bar value=3/>
<br/>
<input class=one type=radio name=car value=1/>
<input class=two type=radio name=car value=2/>
<input class=three type=radio name=car value=3/>
<br/>
```

jquery:

```
$('input').on 'click', ->
    ele=$(this)
    myClass=ele.attr('class')
    $('input.'+myClass).attr('checked',false)
    ele.attr('checked',true)
```